# 14.04.1 report "zero" kilobytes of disk space

Tags: 14.04, filesystem

I have a 400g sata external drive as a backup for /home. I use the default backup app from Ubuntu named: "Backup". The bu drive connects to the 'puter via sata cable. When I powered the drive up today to start a bu, the OS reported 20.5kB available space on root. On re-boot it reported "0" (zero) kB available.

Disk Usage Monitor does not show up on the "Search" box (top left icon on panel).

```
mark@Lexington:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        20G   19G     0 100% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           396M  1.2M  395M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G   31M  2.0G   2% /run/shm
none            100M   40K  100M   1% /run/user
overflow        1.0M   44K  980K   5% /tmp
/dev/sda2       890G  147G  698G  18% /home

mark@Lexington:~$ df -T
Filesystem     Type     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      ext4      20026236  18985908         0 100% /
none           tmpfs            4         0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev           devtmpfs   1980460         4   1980456   1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs       404844      1192    403652   1% /run
none           tmpfs         5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none           tmpfs      2024216     32120   1992096   2% /run/shm
none           tmpfs       102400        40    102360   1% /run/user
overflow       tmpfs         1024        44       980   5% /tmp
/dev/sda2      ext4     933082296 154052376 731608992  18% /home
```

and when the external sata drive is powered up:

```
mark@Lexington:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        20G   19G     0 100% /
```

. . . (as above showing no change)

```
/dev/sdb1       367G  275G   74G  79% /media/mark/80cb5313-35a0-432b-9250-4cc62d79a3c8
```

Comment: What's your question exactly? /dev/sda1, the / partition is too small for you, and is now full. Why is the external HDD relevant?

Comment: I'm not computer savvy enough to respond intelligently to this. The problem appeared when I powered up the external drive. The on-screen message didn't say which drive. But if the OS is reporting a problem like zero disk space, the question must be what is causing this? When the ext. drive is not on, I do not receive the message. Sorry for not being helpful. I don't know what question to ask in this instance.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying. As said, the /dev/sda1 partition is full, with or without the external HDD being connected. So, removing old kernels and headers is a good move, but in the long run, you'll need to expand it.

Answer (score 1):

Today, the filesystem looks very different than a week ago, when I had the warnings. Here it is today:

```
$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       20026236  12591856   6394048  67% /
none                   4         0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             1980460         4   1980456   1% /dev
tmpfs             404844      1204    403640   1% /run
none                5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             2024216     30016   1994200   2% /run/shm
none              102400        64    102336   1% /run/user
/dev/sda2      933082296 152679220 732982148  18% /home
```

`/` is now only 67% used. This is the mostly likely "truth". The original partition was set at about 20 gig. It's about two-thirds in use now. That is what I remember from months ago, when I last had occasion to review space used/available.

This is what I believe happened, as I powered up the external SATA drive, the OS, which doesn't care where the boot drive is, sees that drive as the boot drive, because at one time that now external backup drive was the boot drive with `/` and `/home` and `/usr` and `/var`, etc. While the external drive was re-formatted and had a new EXT4 set, it must have some location where it continues to see the boot partition or some such. I'm not expert enough to fix this, but as the error messages are gone, I believe this was a false alarm. When the external drive is powered up before the OS is powered up, the OS believes the external drive is the bootable device. This is probably due to the external drive being connected via a pci-e card mounted on the motherboard. The card has its own mini BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite normal that u have 100% on your / :

Your / is on a partition of 20G and your /home is on a partition of 367G

Imagine that your "/" is the c: partition and your "/home" is your d: partition in windows, on your "/" you will have your system files and configs ....

type this :

- sudo apt-get clean all
- cd /
- sudo du -csm * --exclude=home |sort -n

this last command will tell u the directories than consume the most on the "/"

You can also use disk analyser in ubuntu to see the files that are eating the space in the "/" and deleted if not need anyone.

** be very careful on removing files in the  "/"
** ask us if you are not sure about files that u dont know.

Comment: I found a way to remove "old" kernels and keep only the new one. I'm sure you fellows know that one, so I won't post it. Between re-boots, yesterday, the OS got an update of rsyslog* and then the problem seems to have stopped. Thank you both for your support.